# jquery click function addclass

Tags: jquery, click

I've got a strange problem where "most" of my rules work inside a click function, but one won't

```
$(".fadeOut input").click(function() {
  $(".nooverlay").addClass("overlayon");
  $(".searchBar").addClass("fadeIn");
  $(".searchBar").removeClass("fadeOut")
});
```

addClass("overlayon") won't work ?!?!?
fadeIn works
fadeOut works

the entire js can be seen here:
https://github.com/TerminalAddict/ta.com-website/blob/master/assets/js/ta.js

I'm using to yui-compressor to compress, then create one big bundle (bundle.js)

no errors in console, and if I paste this function into the console it works fine.

Live demo: https://terminaladdict.com

Comment: I've also tried:

`$("fadeOut").on("click", "input", function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    $(".nooverlay").addClass("overlayon");
    $(".searchBar").addClass("fadeIn");
    $(".searchBar").removeClass("fadeOut")
});`

Comment: What's the purpose of the classes `nooverlay` and `overlayon`?

Comment: overlayon to create a 100% height 100% width overlay with with opaque background, that is clickable (to close the searchbar)

nooverlay, because I though jquery was getting confused by not having an original class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As input box you are target is having an ID and Div element where you are trying to add class is also have an ID. ID's are unique and I think you can use below piece of code. That i also tried executing on console window and seems to be working.

```
$("#query").click(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();

  if($('#query').parents('.fadeOut').length>0){
      $('#overlay').addClass('overlayon');
      $('.searchBar').addClass('fadeIn');
      $('.searchBar').removeClass('fadeOut');
  }
});
```

As We have Black Background to appear only in case of .fadeout class So I have added below code in jquery code above to check if parent of Query Textbox has that class. It seems to be working fine.

```
 if($('#query').parents('.fadeOut').length>0){
```

Comment: makes no difference sorry

Comment: as you also have id to that element can you try with id instead of class like $('#overlay').addclass('overlayon');

Comment: I need to target `$('fadeOut #query)` as I don't want this to run when the searchBar is fadeIn .. let me try

Comment: @TerminalAddict I have updated above code it seems to be working fine on console for all 3 rules. code you gave in question was not working on console also.

Comment: Yes i know fadeout needs to be targetted. I updated code in my last updated for this